# ip command could not get IP address in shell script in crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron

I use Cloudflare API script to update DDNS on my Raspberry PI using crontab. The shell script works fine in Debian but fails in CentOS/Fedora. While run in the terminal, it works.

I checked out the ip addr could not get data, but I could not solve it. And I tried out that I can instead ip addr with hostname -I, then it works well.

But I am wondering why ip could not work in .sh / bash shell script?

Ferora 28 server Raspberry.
I tried many resolvation I can googled, none works.

```
#!/bin/bash
#this works
ip=$(hostname -I | awk '{print $NF;exit}')
echo $ip>>/usr/local/bin/cloudflare.log 

#this fail
ips=$(ip route get 1:: | awk '{print $(NF-4);exit}')
echo $ips>>/usr/local/bin/cloudflare.log 

# crontab -l
#automatic update ddns per 1 min
* */1 * * *  /usr/local/bin/cf-ddns.sh >/dev/null 2>&1

cat cloudflare.log
xx.xx.xxx.xx
<Blank_None>
```

Comment: can you put `echo "IP is $ips"`  just before `echo $ips>>/usr/local/bin/cloudflare.log 
` and if ip is getting  printed ?

Comment: I add `echo "IP is $ips" >>/usr/local/bin/cloudflare.log ` ip did not get printed.

Comment: Add `PATH` solve the problem. But I am very curious why this PATH will leading to `ip route get 1:: ` get an empty value

Comment: its because `cron` needs full path of the binary . More details on google search "full path for cron job"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

crontab dosn't set PATH an cannot find the binarys. Add PATH at the top of your script, or with an export at top of crontab.

```
# for example
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That works for me. But I am very curious why this PATH will leading to `ip route get 1:: ` get an empty value